# pandas; filtering data from a Series into three groups (One, Two, Other)

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently analyzing data from the Stack Overflow Developer Survey, using Jupyter Notebook. If you take a look at the csv file (https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2021.zip), you'll find a column labeled 'Gender'.
Using `df['Gender'].value_counts().plot(kind="bar")` I am able to create a bar graph showing 'Man' and 'Woman', but after that there's over 10 outlying values such as 'Prefer not to say', 'non-binary', 'queer', etc. If you were to combine all these outlying values together they would only make up 4-6%, so it isn't useful for me to have a separate bar for each one. 
What I am trying to figure out is how to combine all the outlying values into a single value called 'Undefined'. This way my bar graph only shows three values (Men, Women, Undefined).

*code:*

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('survey.csv')

df['Gender'].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", figsize=(15,7), color="#61d199")
```

**EDIT**

Solved, here's the updated code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        
df = pd.read_csv('survey.csv')

df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].apply(lambda x: 'Undefined' if x not in ['Man', 'Woman'] else x)
df['Gender'].value_counts().plot(kind="pie", figsize=(10,10), autopct='%1.0f%%', labels=['Men', 'Undefined', 'Women'], 
             colors = ['#98C1D9', '#3D5A80', '#E0FBFC'], title=('Gender Ratio in Programming'))
```

Comment: Just mark anything other than "Men" and "Women" as "Undefined" @Jacob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse your Gender column like this:

```py
df["Gender"] = df["Gender"].apply(lambda x: "Undefined" if x not in ["Men", "Women"] else x)
```